# How to convert a URL or html to pdf with html2pdf JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html2pdf

I am trying to create a button that converts an html page into pdf with the html2pdf library and I would like instead of passing a selected element with query selector or with getElementById pass a url because the page that I want to convert to pdf is not the same as where the button is and therefore I do not take the selector.

I have 3 documents 1 where the button is, 2 the javascript file, 3 the file that I want to convert to pdf.

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
   const $boton = document.querySelector("#btnCrearPdf");
   $boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const $elementoParaConvertir = document.body;
    html2pdf()
        .set({
            margin: 1,
            filename: 'Contrato.pdf',
            image: {
                type: '',
                quality: 0.98
            },
            html2canvas: {
                scale: 3,
                letterRendering: true,
            },
            jsPDF: {
                unit: "in",
                format: "a4",
                orientation: 'portrait'
            }
        })
        .from($elementoParaConvertir)
        .save()
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
   });
   });
```

Comment: You cant :)
Your JS will only work at your site.

Comment: @Veter must there be some way to do it? even with another library

Comment: Its called "web scraping" or "web crawling", and you cant do id from Javascript on client side

Comment: ASKING FOR RECOMMENDATIONS FOR LIBRARIES IS STRICTLY FORBIDDEN

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is basically running your frontend code on another website. For security reasons (it would basically be a kind of hacking), that's not possible.

If the website that you want to convert is your website, put the code there or somehow retrieve the contents of that page/site first. Otherwise, tough luck ;)